# Free WPF Graph control for input / output adjustment

Tags: wpf, graph

Im looking for a nice wpf control to do the following:

1) Present a graph to the user, with points that you can drag to change the curve..

2) During runtime (Backgrond thread not related to WPF) access this curve and give it an input and get an output that corresponds to the curve

A simple example

[image]

An input of 20 would in the example above give an output of about 30

edit: Oh, almost forgot, its a plus if its bindable because I use Caliburn Micro (MVVM)

edit: Solved it with a Curve fit algorithm
[image]

Comment: Hi Anders, did you consider a chart from WPF toolkit? Another thing I would personally try is creating your own ItemsControl - depending on a richness of data it might be easier to bite the bullet and create your very own control.

Comment: Hi. WPF toolkit has no support for draggable points, Dynamic Data Display chart has draggable points.. But its not very bindable friendly and it has no direct feature to get a nice curve and points that change the curve

Comment: Nice curve is nothing but a set of approx'ed values, in .NEt4 you can generate them fairly easily. Id' go along with the draggable points implementation as a base and extend it with a behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a cubic spline interpolation as curve fittting, I ported this one

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SplineInterpolation.aspx

Then for solving Y values for known X values, use this
http://geekswithblogs.net/JuanDoNeblo/archive/2007/10/25/Data-Interpolation-with-SPLINE-in-Csharp.aspx

Result:
[image]